# user is receiving same email twice in java

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am using the code below to send emails using java ,my project is running on a tomcat server. 
the problem that user is receiving same email twice.
after some research it seems that java is sending email twice,any one can help me how I handle it?

```
Properties props;
        Session session;
    try {
                props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "....");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
                props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "2000");
                props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "2000");
                props.setProperty("charset", "utf-8");


                session = Session.getInstance(props,
                        new Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                            }
                        });
    //            session.setDebug(true);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

    try {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

                if (!to.equals("") && to != null) {
                    String[] toArray = to.split(";");
                    InternetAddress[] toList = new InternetAddress[toArray.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < toArray.length; i++) {
                        toList[i] = new InternetAddress(toArray[i]);
                    }

                    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toList);
                }
                if (!cc.equals("") && cc != null) {
                    String[] ccArray = cc.split(";");
                    InternetAddress[] ccList = new InternetAddress[ccArray.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < ccArray.length; i++) {
                        ccList[i] = new InternetAddress(ccArray[i]);
                    }
                    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccList);
                }


                message.setSubject(subject);
                //message.setText(emailBody);
                message.setContent(emailBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                Transport.send(message);

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

Comment: Besides your actual problem , `!cc.equals("") && cc != null`  may give you a nullpointer exception. Take care.

Comment: what are `to`and  `cc` ?

Comment: At this point I'm going to assume the easiest possible answer: the recipient is in the list of recipients twice.

Comment: Gimby some time user is receiving email once ,so I don't think this the problem

Comment: jhamon ,to and cc means the to's and cc's emails

Comment: @RoyYoussef development isn't a guessing game. Prove it through debugging and logging.

Comment: The hint is given by @Gimby: check both `toList` and `ccList` to see if the address is inserted twice.

Comment: i checked this issue ,mails are written correctly

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve errors when sending an email and, moreover, when you want to do something that has been already done from someone else, is by using a library. Open source libraries are used from a lot of developers and their bugs are all the times less than a custom source code. I would suggest you to use [Apache commons Email Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/).
Using this [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html) you can find a lot of examples.